# Which is the best tool for automatic GUI performance testing?

Tags: performance, user-interface, testing

We are currently testing a Java Swing application for it's performance. I wonder if there is a good tool to automate this?

Comment: Do you want to measure the GUI reactivity or the performance of what's behind the GUI, such as the time to load data from the DB ? 
Is your GUI decoupled from the lower layer of the application ?

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I used [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for such a task. I generally enjoyed using it, though I never did much research on what else is available and I don't know if it's still actively developed.

Answer (score 2):

Have a listen to the Pragmatic Programmers's [podcast](http://podcasts.pragprog.com/2008-08/ian-dees-on-scripted-gui-testing-with-ruby.mp3) on using Ruby for GUI testing.

Answer (score 0):

The Pragmatic Programmers also came out with a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356182) on using Ruby to do GUI testing.

In particular, they give extensive examples using JRuby to test a swing app.

The testing they are doing is mostly to test functionality, but I think it would not be hard to add in some performance measures.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you get lots of flexibility, but it is not a packaged tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info) and [Swinger](http://github.com/demetriusnunes/swinger) for writing functional acceptance tests in plain english for Swing GUI applications. Cucumber has an output formatter that includes profiling information.

Cucumber allows you to write tests like this:

```
 Scenario: Dialog manipulation
    Given the frame "SwingSet" is visible
      And the frame "SwingSet" is the container
    When I click the menu "File/About"
    Then I should see the dialog "About Swing!"
    Given the dialog "About Swing!" is the container
    When I click the button "OK"
    Then I should not see the dialog "About Swing!"
```

Take a look at this [Swinger video demo](http://blog.demetriusnunes.com/past/2009/6/9/who_said_you_cant_test_swing_apps/) to see it in action.